# React Native Custom Navbar issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

Hey so I am having a little brain meltdown,

I cannot for the life of me figure out how I should do this.

What I am trying to do is have my custom navbar **not** show on the login screen but show anywhere else.

I explained in this short video: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/643261623519150090/904146526778056805/Desktop_2021.10.30_-_16.10.14.04.mp4

This is my code:

[ root ./ ] **App.js**

```
import LoginScreen from './views/login'
import HomeScreen from './views/home'
import ProfileScreen from './views/profile'


import CustomNav from './views/nav/index'

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
  <View style={styles.Test} >
    <NavigationContainer theme={DarkTheme} linking={{
      config: {
        screens: {
          Login: "/",
          Home: "/home",
          Profile: "/Profile/:Username"
        }
      },
      }}>

      <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false
      }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>

      <CustomNav Nav="Mobile" />

    </NavigationContainer>   
  </View>
  );
}
```

[ ./nav/index] **index.js**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {} from 'react-native';

import MobileNav from './mobile'
import WebsiteNav from './website'


const CustomNav = () => {
    const [viewing, setViewing] = useState('login');

    useEffect(() => {

        if(viewing === 'login'){
            console.log("Viewing Login")
        }else{
            console.log("Not Login")
        }

    }, []);

    return(
        null
    );
}
  
export default CustomNav;
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the best solution but have you tried moving the login screen to its own separate stack navigator? That way you can still navigate from login to home without having that `CustomNav` showing.

Comment: I tried that but the underline issue is still having a way to tell one component to switch to using something else, for example is there a way to make some type of event or something that runs onload of route thank you for the reply